# how to pass the parameter to a form during formset creation

Tags: django, django-forms, formset, inline-formset, otree

I have an inline formset in Django. And I wonder how can I set some `max_value` for a form that is in this formset based on the instance parameters. The problem is that when we create a formset by using `inlineformset_factory` we pass there not an instance of the form, but the class, so I do not know how to pass the parameters there.

when the form is initiated, there is already an `instance` object available in kwargs that are passed there. But for some strange reasons, when I try to set `max_value` nothing happens.
Right now I've found quite an ugly solution to set the widget `max` attribute. This one works but I wonder if there is a correct way of doing it.

```
from .models import SendReceive, Player

from django.forms import inlineformset_factory, BaseFormSet, BaseInlineFormSet


class SRForm(forms.ModelForm):
        amount_sent = forms.IntegerField(label='How much to sent?',
                                         required=True,
                                         widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'min': 0, 'max': 20})
                                         )

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(SRForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            curmax = kwargs['instance'].sender.participant.vars['herd_size']
            self.fields['amount_sent'].widget.attrs['max'] = int(curmax)

        class Meta:
            model = SendReceive
            fields = ['amount_sent']


SRFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Player, SendReceive,
                                      fk_name='sender',
                                      can_delete=False,
                                      extra=0,
                                      form=SRForm,)
formset = SRFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.player)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `functools` to create a curried version of your Form class:

```
from functools import partial, wraps


# create a curried form class
form_with_params = wraps(SRForm)(partial(SRForm, your_param='your_value'))

# use it instead of the original form class
SRFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
                             Player,
                             SendReceive,
                             # ...
                             form=form_with_params,
                           )
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I just solved a bit otherwise, but your solution looks like more universal.
Here is how I did it: https://gist.github.com/chapkovski/b6fd6134124d88d671ed7b3b1baa4b81
So instead of re-writing `max_value` it was enough to re-write an entire field in init.